# How do you add multiple links of the same type to a resource using Spring HATEOAS?

Tags: hateoas, spring-hateoas

The [HAL spec that I am working with](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) says that you can have multiple links of the same type on a resource like this:

```
{
    "_links": {
      "items": [{
          "href": "/first_item"
      },{
          "href": "/second_item"
      }]
    }
}
```

However Spring `ResourceSupport` type only seems to have an `add()` method that adds a single link.   So I can write

`order.add(linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class).order(id)).withRel("item"));`

to add one such, but I can't see how to get an array of them with a ref as `items`, as per the spec.

Comment: Can you call it twice?

Comment: I'll be darned that works!   You should add that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `ResourceSupport::add()` twice (or more) with the same withRel value, it creates an array ref with that name containing each of the items.